# Movement Position Being Equal to Int

Tags: unityscript

I wasn't exactly sure how to title this, however I will explain what I mean. I am trying to make my game object move using:

`transform.translate(Vector2.up \* moveSpeed * time.deltaTime);`
Now what I want to do next is what is causing some trouble. I would like the object to continue moving until it hits the Y value of 1, and then turn left. I almost have that working. See it WILL work if I use >= 1, because it skips over the value of 1 (not moving by choppy ints). Even if I try changing it to == 1.0f it still won't work as I guess the object is moving too quickly and skips over some values. We've tried re-positioning it in the >= block of code but that bugs out and doesn't work very well.

If you have any thoughts or possible solutions that would be great! Thanks! :-D

Code ex:

```
  if (transform.position.x <= -2 && transform.position.y < -1) {
 transform.Translate(Vector2.up * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
 else if (transform.position.y <= -4)
 {
 transform.Translate(Vector2.left * playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Did my explanation did the trick or did something go wrong? Youre not giving any feedback

Comment: well, could you please give some more information because you did not give much... and link is broken.. You'd have to tell what you want from your post and why current answers are not doing the trick. We cannot pinpoint what you desire without explicit information

Comment: Sounds like you would benefit from reviewing kinematics. Here are [the main equations](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/1DKin/Lesson-6/Kinematic-Equations), which should be enough to help you figure out how to code a simple physics-based simulation/prediction.

Comment: Got busy sorry Hmm with the comment of @serlite did you unblock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really match what you want from your gif. Although,  what you need is fairly simple when you think of adding a bool value called didCollidHappen and implement the OnCollideEnter method in your script. 
Doing so, when you call Update at each frame, you will verify if there were any collisions and then call the code to make your game object jump. What follows is a code snippet. Insert it in your C# script :-)

```
public bool didCollideHappen =false;

public void OnCollideEnter(Collision col)
{
  if(col.gameObject.tag ==  "Something")//if it's any game object, then just put bool value to true !! 
  {
     didCollidedHappen = true; 
  }
}

public void MakeSlowedJump()
{
      actualSpeed -= slowAmount * Time.fixedDeltaTime; 
      transform.position += new Vector3 (0.13F, actualSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, 0);
}


public void Update()
{
    if(didCollideHappen)
         MakeSlowedJump();
 }
```